# length of a curve defined by $\gamma(t) = (\cos^3t,\sin^3t)\;\;t\in[0,2\pi]$

Tags: geometry, curves, arc-length

according to wolframalpha 
$\ell(\gamma) = 6$

but I found $0$ and I still haven't figured out where's my mistake.

my attempt :

$$\gamma(t) = (\cos^3t,\sin^3t) \implies \gamma'(t) = 3(-\sin t\cos^2 t,\cos t\sin^2 t)  $$
so
$$||\gamma'(t)||^2 =9(\sin^2 t\cos^4 t+\cos^2 t\sin^4 t) = 9(\sin^2 t(\cos^2 t(\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t))) = 9\sin^2 t \cos^2 t$$
$$||\gamma'(t)|| = 3\sin t \cos t=\frac32\sin(2t)$$
$$\ell(\gamma)=\int_0^{2\pi}||\gamma'(t)||dt =\frac32\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(2t)dt = \frac34[-\cos(2t)]_0^{2\pi} =0$$

can someone please point out where I did something wrong ?

Comment: $||\gamma^{\prime}(t)||=\frac{3}{2}|\sin(2t)|$. As you've seen, the absolute value is crucial.

Comment: @ carmichael561 I was so confused pfff... thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this curve will lie in all the four quadrants. To calculate the length of this curve it is enough to calculate the length in the first quadrant. Now use the formula for length, $l= \int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\sqrt{1+ (\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx$

So by symmetry we have,
\begin{align*}
l &= 4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{d}{dt}(\cos^3t)\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{d}{dt}(\sin^3 t)\bigg)^2}dt \\
&=4\int_0^{\pi/2}3\sqrt{\cos^4t\sin^2t+ \sin^4t\cos^2t} \ dt \\
&= 12\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos t\sin t \ dt  = 6
\end{align*}

Comment: The curve is an astroid : see (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Astroid.html) where you will find many details on this curve including its length.